# Figure for a physics problem

Tags: tikz-graphs

I want to copy this figure, but I cannot do it since I'm new to LaTeX, can anyone help me? I tried using the equation `$x=\sqrt{1-(y+1)^{2}}$`, but I can't seem to plot it on TikZ. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! Yes, LaTeX does have tools to draw arcs.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,chains,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{% 
    attach arrow/.style={
    decoration={
        markings,
         mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrow/length}/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}%
         \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
        mark=at position {#1-3*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
        mark=at position {#1-2*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@2);},
        mark=at position {#1-1*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@3);},
        mark=at position {#1+\tmpArrowTime/2} with {\coordinate(@4);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrow/length},bend]}] plot[smooth]
         coordinates {(@1) (@2) (@3) (@4)};},
        },
     postaction=decorate,
     },
     attach arrow/.default=0.5,
     arc arrow/.cd,length/.initial=2mm,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[bend]},thick]
 \draw[help lines,step=5mm] (0,-5) grid (4,1);
 \draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,1) node[right]{$y$};
 \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (4,0) node[below left]{$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,0) node[midway,above]{$v$};
 \draw[attach arrow] 
 (0,0) node[draw,fill=white,inner sep=2pt,circle,label=below left:$O$]{} 
 arc[start angle=90,end angle=-90,radius=2]
 node[circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label=left:$P$]{};
 \path (2.2,-3.5) 
 node[draw,double distance=1pt,inner sep=2pt,circle,label=below right:$B$]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. How about the grid?

Comment: @Therizinosauruscheloniformis Well, it is easy to add if there is a clear prescription for it. Your question asks `tried using the equation $x=\sqrt{1-(y+1)^{2}}$, but I can't seem to plot it on TikZ`, which suggested to me that you wanted the arc. If you add some explanation for the grid it can be added with `patterns.meta`. However, I am not keen on looking at a graphics and measuring the relative positions of the dots.

Comment: I'm really sorry that I didn't add any explanation regarding the grid. Would you be kind to explain how to do the grid?

Comment: @Therizinosauruscheloniformis Would you please so kind to explain the rules that underly the grid?

Comment: The grid represents a magnetic field. I think any type of grid will do.

Comment: I have to say, it would have been very satisfying to see this random-intensity-dot-pattern-on-a-grid-kind-of-thing being reproduced, too :).

Comment: @MatthiasArras You can ask a follow-up question. I am very disappointed by getting almost completely copied by another user (without proper attribution). Several users have quit because of such behavior, and the more one supports those copiers, the less likely it will be that others spend time on working out a solution. It is not very satisfying for me to see that those copiers get as much credit as the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the @Schrödinger's cat answer, but less sophisticated:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
->-/.style = {decoration={markings,
              mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Stealth}}}, thick,
              postaction={decorate}},
         > = Stealth,
dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill=#1, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]

\draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,1) node[below left]{$y$};
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (4,0) node[below left]{$x$};
\draw[very thin, dotted, step=5mm] (0,1) grid (4,-5);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- node[above] {$v$}    (1,0) ;
\draw[->-]      (0,0) arc (90:-90:2);
%
\node[dot=white, label=below left:$O$] at (0,0) {};
\node[dot=black, label=left:$P$] at (0,-4) {};
\node[dot=white,double,label=below right:$B$] at (2,-3.5) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, this is almost completely copied from my answer except that you add a mark `\arrow{Stealth[bend]}` where `bend` has no effect.

Comment: Interesting "passe d'armes" as we say in French...